# Why am I getting "`OSError: unknown file format`" when opening a TTF with `PIL.ImageFont`?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

In Google Colab I am using `PIL` (Python Imaging Library). I have uploaded a TrueType Font `MSMINCHO.TTF`.

I am attempting to read it with `fnt_kanji = ImageFont.truetype('./MSMINCHO.TTF')` but I get the error "`OSError: unknown file format`".

I know the font is valid because it displays correctly in my local system. And the encoding is Unicode as it should be, since this font contains kanji (Chinese characters). And the filepath is also valid and correctly cased (otherwise, "`OSError: cannot open resource`" is thrown instead).

I've been searching for the solution in the docs and the web for more than half an hour and haven't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your line to:

```
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('./MSMINCHO.TTF', layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_BASIC)
```

if that doesn't work you can try refreshing your pillow module like this:

```
pip uninstall pillow
python3 -m pip install -U https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work. Also, I'm using Google Colab, so I have no direct access to the command line or the pip package manager.

Comment: my understanding was that in Google Colab you can use command line commands by adding an exclamation mark before them like ```!pip uninstall pillow```

Comment: Sorry this was so long ago, but I think in the end it must have worked and I forgot to upvote.